# Can you use Java EE frameworks with the Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, stripes

I have been working on a small web app using the Stripes framework. Now that the Google App Engine has added support for Java, I am wondering if I can convert it to run in the Google App Engine to save costs on hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it supports servlets, so it should support [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) just fine.

According to the App Engine [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html),

> App Engine uses the Java Servlet
>   standard for web applications. You
>   provide your app's servlet classes,
>   JavaServer Pages (JSPs), static files
>   and data files, along with the
>   deployment descriptor (the web.xml
>   file) and other configuration files,
>   in a standard WAR directory structure.
>   App Engine serves requests by invoking
>   servlets according to the deployment
>   descriptor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I assumed that the Google App Engine would have support for existing J2EE web frameworks, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be [a little snag (and workaround)](http://www.nabble.com/Stripes-and-Google-App-Engine-td22948917.html) because of the missing access to a local temporary directory. You need to provide your own file upload facility (or disable the feature).

Answer (score 2):

Took this from [RoR on GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753031/ror-on-gae/753250#753250)

More information:

- [Official Working Library List](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine)
- [Unofficial Working Library List](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pRJ%5F0hajVrhacLjp3HqD5ew)